# Object of class Registration could not be converted to int

Tags: yii

```
$model_reg_b = BusinessNatureMappingForm::model()->findbyPk($model_reg);
foreach ($model_reg_b->BusinessNatureMappingForm as $keyi1 => $model_reg_bb) {
    $model_ownerm = OwnershipSpecificDetailsForm::model()->findByAttributes(array("bnsd_bnmid" => $model_reg_bb->bnm_regid));
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation.

Comment: m trying to retrieve value of $model_ownerm in index.php ...

Comment: I can't understand your question please explai better your problem and your goal, the errors if therea are

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use a model as the parameter of `findbyPk()` instead of a primary key attribute (e.g. `$model_reg->id`).

Change this:

```
$model_reg_b = BusinessNatureMappingForm::model()->findbyPk($model_reg);
```

To this:

```
$model_reg_b = BusinessNatureMappingForm::model()->findbyPk($model_reg->primary_key_column);
```